# I'm stuck in an endless loop trying to get info to my python api and then use that info from the nextjs app to run the python script with it

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, next.js

I get Response: Error sending data. It works when it doesn't data to retrieve in server.py when it's already specified in the code. like instead of "msg_user" when it's an actual user to message

I think it could maybe be because of the data.get or because it's only a POST api should be probably GET? I honestly don't know much and i'm trying to learn and i'm very stuck here, i've asked chatgpt about a million times and it's the same thing over and over again i've been going through this code for hours maybe i'm missing something so I would love some feedback

THIS IS INDEX.TSX

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function SendMessage() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
     user: '',
     pass1: '',
     msg_user: '',
     the_msg: '',
  });

  const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      // Make a POST request to your Flask API
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/send-message', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData), // Send the form data to the API
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setResponseMessage(data.message);
      } else {
        setResponseMessage(`Error: ${data.error}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending data:', error);
      setResponseMessage('Error sending data.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Send Instagram Message</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Username:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="user"
            value={formData.user}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password:
          <input
            type="password"
            name="pass1"
            value={formData.pass1}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Username:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="msg_user"
            value={formData.msg_user}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Message:
          <textarea
            name="the_msg"
            value={formData.the_msg}
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></textarea>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
      </form>
      {responseMessage && <p>Response: {responseMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

THIS IS SERVER.PY

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS  # Import CORS
from instagrapi import Client

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins='http://localhost:3000')  # Allow requests from http://localhost:3000

@app.route('/send-message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    try:
        # Retrieve information from the POST request data
        data = request.get_json()
        user = data.get("user")
        pass1 = data.get("pass1")
        msg_user = data.get("msg_user")
        the_msg = data.get("the_msg")

        # Initialize the Instagram client
        cl = Client()
        cl.login(user, pass1)
        send_to = cl.user_id_from_username(username=msg_user)
        
        # Send the direct message
        cl.direct_send(text=the_msg, user_ids=[send_to])

        return jsonify({"message": "Message sent successfully!"})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Did the request reach the server? Do you know if the error is thrown by client-side or server-side? What's the return status code? I am suspecting it is a server-side problem and it in this line `cl.direct_send(text=the_msg, user_ids=[send_to])` but you can help provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the details of the other codes you provide. Yet I found that you set the port as 5000 in the front-end app to fetch data but 3000 in your flask-api. You can check if it is the problem.
Another thing is that your front-end app seems to be a client-side server, so if you are using the latest version of next.js, you need to add 'use client' on top of your code.

Comment: It was actually that simple and that fixed it, thanks dude. crazy how I missed that